# How to store result from Web3 web3.eth.getAccounts()

Tags: web3js

```
 var defaultAccount;

 web3.eth.getAccounts(function(error, result){ 
      defaultAccount = result[0];
 });

 console.log(defaultAccount);
```

It logs "undefined" on console. How do I store it on defaultAccount var and set it afterwards to:

```
web3.eth.defaultAccount = defaultAccount;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign the promise to an outside variable, only return it.
Try this:

```
web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.getAccounts(function(error, result){ 
      return result[0];
});
```